# using tcp wrappers

Tags: networking

editing my hosts.allow to allow and deny access to special services.
At last restart service without rebooting the system.
Try ***killall -HUP inetd*** or ***killall -HUP xinetd***

The answer

> inetd: no procces found

or

> xinetd: no procces found

makes me stump. A system without running inetd?

How to restart the NIC's without rebooting system?

My System is actual elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya

Christian

Answer (score 1):

To restart the NIC run `ifconfig`. You should see something like the following

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.3  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::8634:97ff:fe89:f64e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:46371176 (46.3 MB)  TX bytes:4144187 (4.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:246769 (246.7 KB)  TX bytes:246769 (246.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:** 
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

In the example I will be using **eth0** but yours could be different.If you use WiFi it will be something like **wlan0**. Now run the following to restart your NIC.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Replace **eth0** (in bold) with your NIC.